# Custom SchemaIndexProviders and OnlineAccessors

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to build a custom indexing solution for Neo4j 2.1.2. The `IndexPopulator` gets notifications for all the population events before the index becomes online. After `getOnlineAccessor` is called, however, the IndexAccessor doesn't get notified about changes to nodes and properties. I was expecting `process` to get called with those events. Am I missing something about how custom indexes should be configured?

The provider factory:

```java
@Service.Implementation(KernelExtensionFactory.class)
public class IndexProviderFactory extends KernelExtensionFactory<Dependencies> {

  public static final String KEY = "index";

  public SchemaIndexProvider.Descriptor DESCRIPTOR = new SchemaIndexProvider.Descriptor(KEY, "1.0");

  private final Supplier<CustomIndexSchemaProvider> provider =
      new Supplier<CustomIndexSchemaProvider>() {
        @Override
        public CustomIndexSchemaProvider get() {
          return new CustomIndexSchemaProvider();
        }
      };

  public IndexProviderFactory() {
    super(KEY);
  }

  @Override
  public Lifecycle newKernelExtension(Dependencies dependencies) throws Throwable {
    return Suppliers.memoize(provider).get();
  }

}
```

And the actual test case with the bulk of the custom provider:

```java
public class IndexTest {

  static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(IndexTest.class.getName());
  static Label LABEL = DynamicLabel.label("foo");

  @Test
  public void testUpdate() throws Exception {
    GraphDatabaseService db = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();
    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
      final IndexCreator indexCreator = db.schema().indexFor(LABEL).on("bar");
      indexCreator.create();
      tx.success();
    }
    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
      db.schema().awaitIndexesOnline(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      tx.success();
    }
    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
      Node node = db.createNode(LABEL);
      node.setProperty("bar", 1);
      tx.success();
    }
    db.shutdown();
  }

  static interface Dependencies {
    Config getConfig();
  }

  static class CustomIndexSchemaProvider extends SchemaIndexProvider {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger
        .getLogger(CustomIndexSchemaProvider.class.getName());

    LoggingIndex index = new LoggingIndex();

    public CustomIndexSchemaProvider() {
      super(DESCRIPTOR, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPopulationFailure(long indexId) throws IllegalStateException {
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public InternalIndexState getInitialState(long indexId) {
      return InternalIndexState.POPULATING;
    }

    @Override
    public IndexAccessor getOnlineAccessor(long indexId, IndexConfiguration config)
        throws IOException {
      logger.info("getOnlineAccessor " + indexId);
      return index;
    }

    @Override
    public IndexPopulator getPopulator(long indexId, IndexDescriptor descriptor,
        IndexConfiguration config) {
      logger.info("getPopulator for " + indexId);
      return index;
    }

    public static class LoggingIndex extends IndexAccessor.Adapter implements IndexPopulator,
        IndexUpdater, IndexAccessor {

      @Override
      public void add(long nodeId, Object propertyValue) {
        logger.info("add " + propertyValue);
      }

      @Override
      public void process(NodePropertyUpdate update) throws IOException,
          IndexEntryConflictException {
        logger.info("process " + update);
      }

      @Override
      public void remove(Iterable<Long> nodeIds) throws IOException {}

      @Override
      public void markAsFailed(String failure) throws IOException {}

      @Override
      public void create() {}

      @Override
      public void close(boolean populationCompletedSuccessfully) {}

      @Override
      public void verifyDeferredConstraints(PropertyAccessor accessor) throws Exception {}

      @Override
      public IndexUpdater newPopulatingUpdater(PropertyAccessor accessor) throws IOException {
        return this;
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnlineIndexProxy` calls `newUpdater` (not `newPopulatingUpdater`) in the  `IndexAccessor.Adapter`. Adding this to my `LoggingIndex` solves the issue:

```java
@Override
public IndexUpdater newUpdater(IndexUpdateMode mode) {
  return this;
}
```